# NPM Run Build Always Builds Production and Never Development

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

On an inherited project I have, I am trying to get the build command to build a version other than `Production`.

I have attempted to change the alias in the `script` section in `package.json` to pass in extra variables such as `--dev` and `--configuration=dev` to no avail.

---

The project has these json data files:

```
 env.dev
 env.development
 env.production
```

with the `package.json` has this build alias `build:dev` which I run `npm run build:dev`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev && react-scripts start",
    …
    "build:dev": "npm run build --dev --configuration=dev && react-scripts build"
}
```

This works and builds, but for production only which I verify when I view the resultant files.

---

If I remove the file `env.production` from the directory and run the build command, it fails with:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'polyfills' in 'C:\Work\MyProj\WebSiteName\src'
```

which just informs me that it can alias `polyfills` found in the `env.production` file for the location `NODE_PATH=src/`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

you need to set the env. variable like you do in "start" before calling the build command.

`"build:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run build --dev --configuration=dev && react-scripts build"`

Comment: on windows use `"build:dev": "SET NODE_ENV=dev npm run build --dev --configuration=dev && react-scripts build"` - i.e. prepend NODE_ENV with SET

Comment: Setting the `NODE_ENV` doesn't affect it, whether using `env NODE_ENV`, calling `export NODE_ENV=dev` prior to running the build, or putting it in an `.env` file